# Cannot get intersecting points of polygons in canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am currently drawing two random polygons in canvas and want to find their intersecting points so I could use those x and y coordinates to merge polygons as one at the end. Even though polygons are crossing each other, none of its coordinates is matching. Would you let me know if there is any way I could find that?

```
const Canvas: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [drawingState, setDrawingState] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [startingStateX, setStartingStateX] = useState(0);
  const [startingStateY, setStartingStateY] = useState(0);
  const [currentDrawing, setCurrentDrawing] = useState<number[][]>([]);
  const [drawnObject, setDrawnObject] = useState<number[][][]>([]);

  const { current } = canvasRef;
  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
  if (current !== null) {
    ctx = current.getContext("2d");
  }

  const initiateDrawing = (x: number, y: number) => {
    setDrawingState(true);
    setStartingStateX(x);
    setStartingStateY(y);
    draw(x, y);
  };

  const draw = (x: number, y: number) => {
    if (drawingState && ctx !== null) {
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      setCurrentDrawing((prev: number[][]) => [...prev, [x, y]]);
    }
  };

  const endDrawing = () => {
    setDrawingState(false);
    if (ctx !== null) {
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.lineTo(startingStateX, startingStateY);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.beginPath();
      setDrawnObject((prev: number[][][]) => [...prev, currentDrawing]);
      setCurrentDrawing([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="canvasWrapper">
        <canvas
          onMouseDown={(e) => initiateDrawing(e.clientX, e.clientY)}
          onMouseUp={endDrawing}
          onMouseMove={(e) => draw(e.clientX, e.clientY)}
          ref={canvasRef}
          width={window.innerWidth * 0.8}
          height={window.innerHeight}
        />
      </div>
      <List drawnObject={drawnObject} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

And the bottom is the logics that I made to find the intersecting points.

```
interface listProps {
  drawnObject: number[][][];
}

const List: React.FC<listProps> = (props: listProps) => {
  const [clickedPolygon, setClickedPolygon] = useState<number[][][]>([]);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const handleClickedPolygon = (index: number, polygon: number[][]) => {
    const checkIndex = clickedIndex.indexOf(index);
    if (checkIndex === -1) {
      setClickedIndex((prev: number[]) => [...prev, index]);
      setClickedPolygon((prev: number[][][]) => [
        ...prev,
        props.drawnObject[index],
      ]);
    } else {
      const updatedIndexList = clickedIndex.filter((el) => el !== index);
      setClickedIndex(updatedIndexList);
      const updatedPolygonList = clickedPolygon.filter((el, i) => i !== index);
      setClickedPolygon(updatedPolygonList);
    }
  };

  const findCrossingPoint = () => {
    const maxIndex = clickedPolygon.reduce(
      (acc, cur, idx, arr) => (arr[acc].length >= cur.length ? acc : idx),
      0
    );
    const startPolygon = clickedPolygon[maxIndex];
    for (let i = 0; i < startPolygon.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < clickedPolygon.length; j++) {
        if (j !== maxIndex) {
          for (let k = 0; k < clickedPolygon[j].length; k++) {
            if (
              startPolygon[i][0] === clickedPolygon[j][k][0] &&
              startPolygon[i][1] === clickedPolygon[j][k][1]
            ) {
              console.log(startPolygon[i][0]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="listContainer">
      {props.drawnObject.length !== 0 &&
        props.drawnObject.map((object, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="object">
            <input
              id="object"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={() => handleClickedPolygon(index, object)}
            />
            <label htmlFor="object">Polygon {index}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      {props.drawnObject.length !== 0 && (
        <div id="buttonContainer">
          <div onClick={findCrossingPoint}>merge selected</div>
          <div onClick={() => console.log(props.drawnObject)}>export all</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is but the code you present will not works due to using non existing events. `onMouseDown`, `onMouseUp`, and  `onMouseMove`,  should be `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, and  `onmousemove`,  For some reason all DOM events use only lowercase names (guessing someone somewhere did not get the `camelCase` memo when setting out the specifications)

Answer (score 0):

Merging two polygons is quite a complicated problem. Since the polygons are random (i.e. including non-convex and self-intersecting cases) it brings even more complexity. But even with simple convex polygons case you'll get multiple intersection points, so getting the intersection points is just a small piece of the algorithm.

Back to the finding intersection points problem. A naive solution would be the following:

- loop through the sides of polygon A
- loop through the sides of polygon B
- calculate an intersection of the current side of poly A with the current side of poly B (there are many algorithms for that, e.g. check out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(Euclidean_geometry)#Two_line_segments))

I believe there are more sophisticated algorithms that work much faster than the above, you can try to google them.

As a next step (to merge polygons) you have to walk through each pair of intersecting sides and determine which of the four resulting sub-segments should be a part of the new polygon and which should be discarded. Normally the ones which are located inside poly A or poly B should be discarded (see [Point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem), but beware of the cases when one side of poly A intersects more than one side of poly B.

So as you can see the problem is rather mathematical than JS- or React-related. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But the problem right now is that I already have logics to loop through both polygon A and B to find whether there are any same/matching coordinates(since they are crossing each other) but there is none. I just wonder whether I have to apply another codes in order to have the intersecting coordinates for canvas tag when I extract.  tried canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(); but it was not working either.

Comment: Hm... I don't think I get it. So you have a function to search for the matching points between two polygons, and there's no any. This is fine, because in most cases their _sides_ intersect, rather than having common vertices. So yes, you need to implement additional function that calculates these intersections. Start with a simple function that calculates intersection point of two line segments and then apply it to each pair of the polygons' sides.

Comment: @Paige you said `I already have logics to loop through both polygon A and B to find ...` but that is not in the code sample you presented on the question, do you mind adding that

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I attached logic to the question! Please check it once you could!

Comment: @yuvin I will try it!